# How to get logs while running Azure functions locally?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm developing / debugging my Function App locally on mac High Sierra by azure-functions-core-tools v2.2.70. My app is based on Node.js 8.11.1.

When my app is published on Azure, I can get the logs which are logged by `context.log("sample message")`, however, while running the app locally by `func host start`, I don't see any of my customs logs. That is, if I log something by context.log or console.log, I will not see it.

I even tried `NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect func host start`, but even that didn't help.

Can you please tell me how can I get my custom logs? Because without logging, debugging gets difficult.

FYI, in my host.json, I have following:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "tracing": {
    "consoleLevel": "verbose"
  },
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always"
  }
}
```

Comment: With default host.json `{"version": "2.0"}`, host should output custom logs as expected. Have you tried to reinstall function core tools?  Besides, `tracing` is only for v1 function.

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "default": "Debug"
        }
    }
}
```

It allowed me to see log output in the terminal when starting with `func host start` (CLI)

Comment: When you say "This worked for me", worked how? In terms of the log writing locally? If so, where does it write to?

Comment: @StevePettifer this also "worked for me".  In the same way which the answer says: showing the log output in the terminal when starting with `func host start`.

Comment: Does not work for me. It's driving me crazy. Why would they mess up with console.log. Context.log does not even print on terminal.

Comment: At least in my case, modifying my host.json to include this code enabled me to view my logs in the terminal output in vscode, I suspect that is where most of these upvotes come from.